# The math problem is too difficult for `X` to work out

Tags: slang

There are four options: everybody, somebody, anybody and nobody.
Which one should be used in `X` place ?

Comment: *Nobody* would never be acceptable. Of the other three, *somebody* is unlikely, but just about feasible in certain contrived contexts - or maybe when *somebody* is a facetious usage meaning ***you*** (the person being addressed). The difference between using *everybody* and *anybody* is General Reference (if you use *everybody*, you're implying that *some, but not all* people can work it out; if you use *anybody* you're saying there aren't any people at all who can work it out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As FF has pointed out, only *everybody* and *anybody* are acceptable
(*everyone* and *anyone* also work). They work, and the others don't, for the same reasons:

1. *Too* is a [**Negative**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) -- ***too* `Adj` *to* `VP`** means '***so* `Adj` *that* `Not VP`**';
   therefore [NPIs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) like *anyone* work within its scope,
   and so *anybody* is used here, instead of *somebody*.

   That's also why *nobody* is ungrammatical here, because that would mean
   **The math problem is so difficult that nobody can't work it out.*
   which is ungrammatical (that's what the "*" means).
2. *Everybody, somebody*, and *anybody* are all **Quantifiers** -- [logically](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), ***∀*** and ***∃***.
   By [DeMorgan's Laws](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/demorgan.pdf), propositions with both a negative and a quantifier are [ambiguous](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/q-neg.html).

   > Note the opposite orders of ***not*** (logically ***¬***),
   >   compared to ***some/any*** (***∃***) and ***every*** (***∀***) below.

   I.e, *Everybody doesn't like it*
   can mean 
   **either**
   *It is true that there is **somebody** who does **not** like it.*
   ¬(∀x) φ(x) ≡ (∃x) ¬φ(x)
   **or**
   *It's **not** true that there is **somebody** who likes it.*
   ¬(∃x) φ(x) ≡ ∀(x) ¬φ(x)

So the two choices that are grammatical do not mean the same thing.

- *The test is too difficult for everybody to figure out* means
  'The test is so difficult that there are **some** people who can **not** figure it out'
- *The test is too difficult for anybody to figure out* means
  'The test is so difficult that there are **no** people who **can** figure it out'

Answer (score 1):

Which of *everybody, somebody, anybody* and *nobody* should be used depends on the meaning to be conveyed. If the meaning is that the problem is so difficult that nobody can work it out, then (as other answers indicate) the best fit is:

> The math problem is too difficult for anybody to work out.

If, however, the meaning is: *Nobody finds the problem too difficult to work out*, then *nobody* fits:

> The math problem is too difficult for nobody.

Admittedly, adding back the (superfluous) *to work out* makes the sentence now sound a little awkward:

> The math problem is too difficult for nobody to work out.

So I prefer:

> The math problem is too difficult to work out for nobody

with appropriate prosody.

Answer (score 0):

The fifth option is the pronoun **one**, as in *The problem is too difficult for one to work out*.

This usage is synonymous with the usage described by **FumbleFingers** above of *anybody*, but I believe is a more likely usage in dialogue or conversation.