# Is it wrong to use 'not" in sentences that have an “all…not” form

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis, semantics

> All of the women in the district did not vote for the lone female candidate.

What, if any, is the semantic problem in the above sentence?

I was suggested the following sentence by my senior peers.

> “Not all of the women in the district voted for the lone female candidate.”

Comment: This form (which has always seemed odd to me) is sanctioned by venerable usage, in particular in the proverb "All that glisters is not gold". In general I prefer paraphrases like your second sentence.

Comment: @ColinFine Somehow I do not find "All that glisters is not gold" in any way similar to "All of the women in the district did not vote." Neither syntactically nor semantically.

Comment: Aditya, do not use the irregular form "All of the women in the district did not vote" -- it is neither correct not makes proper sense.

Comment: Thank you and all, and i never imagined i could get such cogent explanation. ELU is into great hands and would remain the #1...No competition et al.

Comment: @Kris: I find the two exactly parallel in the relevant features: _All ... [neg vb]_, with its attendant ambiguity of whether the _all_ is within the scope of the _not_ or not. But Aditya's first example is neither irregular, nor incorrect, nor fails to make sense. It is merely ambiguous.

Comment: @ColinFine Sounds like a great discovery for me: what is "merely ambiguous," yet "is neither irregular, nor incorrect, nor fails to make sense?" Any help?

Comment: @Kris: I don't know how to answer you. Many sentences are ambiguous without being in any useful sense wrong or irregular or senseless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question, as posed, is

- *Is it wrong to use “not” in sentences that have an “all…not” form?*

and the answer, as far as I can reckon it, is that it's not.
It is never wrong to use *not*. If that's what you mean, of course.

I don't quite understand what you mean by *sentences that have an “all…not” form*,
but I don't imagine you do, either. Description of syntactic structures is hard.

What's going on in the example question

- *All of the women in the district did not vote for the lone female candidate.*

is that there is a quantifier (*all*) and a negative (*not*) in the same proposition,
and when that happens there occurs what is called a [Quantifier-Negative Ambiguity](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/134190/15299).
That is, there are [two possible ways](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/183118/15299) in which the negative and the quantifier can interact.

Either it means `All Women (Not Vote X)` [i.e, "All the women voted non-X"], or
it means `Not (All Women Vote X)` [i.e, "All the women voted X" is **False** -- someone voted non-X].

This ambiguity is likely and often unavoidable in all of the following environments:

- at least one negative and a quantifier in a single clause
- at least one epistemic quantifier (*some, any*) and one universal quantifer (*all, every*), ditto
- at least one [Possible ('Diamond') modal and one Necessary ('Square') modal, ditto](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html).

because quantifiers, negatives, and modals are [all logical operators which bind a focus.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the intended meaning is not clear. The intended meaning could have been:

*Not all of the women in the district voted for the lone female candidate*,
*Some' but not all, of the women in the district voted for the lone female candidate*

or

*All of the women in the district voted against the lone female candidate, or abstained.*

Answer (score 2):

When I read your first sentence, I took the meaning to be "*None of the women in the district voted for the lone female candidate.*" If this is not your intended meaning, then the sentence requires clarification. I do not agree with your peers' suggestion, as it adds an assumption to the original sentence (like I did above). As to the actual question, "*all nouns did not verb*" equates to "*No nouns verbed*" in my mind. I just used verbed. Sigh.

Comment: As John Lawler says, that is one possible interpretation of "all nouns did not verb", but not the only one.