# "Didn't any" and "didn't either"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

> A discount will be given to teams that did not participate in either of the last two EBL Team Championships held in Budapest 2016 and Ostend 2018.

Who qualifies for a discount?

1. Teams that didn't play both of these two championships.
2. Teams that didn't play at least one of these two championships.

The same question with "either" replaced with "any".

Comment: This is a typical Quantifier-Negative Ambiguity. See John Lawler's answer at [Is the sentence below ambiguous?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586261/is-the-sentence-below-ambiguous/586264#586264) The sentence is inherently ambiguous, though people can (as is obviously the situation in the answers given) argue that one or other reading should be assumed as the default.

Answer (score 1):

*Did not participate in either* means *failed to participate in both.* Otherwise I think *participated in only one* would have been used.

*Any* would only be used if more than two championships were involved.

Comment: This is so confusing. Why not using "both" if you want to say both? Either sounds like one of two.

Comment: I'd say the default reading is the one Hellion gives. But this is a typical Quantifier-Negative Ambiguity. See John Lawler's answer at [Is the sentence below ambiguous?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586261/is-the-sentence-below-ambiguous/586264#586264)

Answer (score 1):

"Teams that did not participate in either game" means "teams that played in zero of the two games that were played."

"Teams that did not participate in both games" means "teams that played in less than two of the two games played" (could be zero of the two, could be one of the two.)

"Teams that did not participate in any of the games" means "teams that played in zero of the (presumably more than two) games that were played."

I would hazard to guess that it's the negative aspect of these constructs that is throwing you off:  "either" = "one (or possibly two) of the two", while "neither" or "not either" is "none of the two".

Comment: This is another application of [De Morgan’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) because "not (Budapest-2016 or Ostend-2018)" is the same as "not Budapest-2016 and not Ostend-2018".